# Sink drain popped off when sink was full

Tags: plumbing, sink, pvc

While draining a full sink, this pipe came out.

[image]

1. What is the proper name of the white rotating nut-like part?
2. I reattached the pipe and hand-tightened the nut.  Should I do anything else?
3. Is there something else likely wrong?  Is this worth calling a plumber?

Any advice would be helpful, I have exactly 0 plumbing knowledge.

Comment: Looks like your tailpiece is really short; maybe the compression ring wasn't on tight enough and the pressure head of the full sink popped it loose.

Comment: Do you have a p-trap? If not, you have more problems than just that. Take a wide picture that shows everything under the sink.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you have all the parts in there so unscrew the white nut all the way and hold it up on to the tail pipe. There should be a plastic compression ring so slide that up on to the tail pipe. Now take your drain pipe and slide it on to the tail pipe as far as it will go. Start to tighten the white nut while pushing the drain pipe up on to the tail pipe. Hand tighten the white nut. Get some adjustable pliers, Channelocks, and tighten the white nut about a quarter turn. Directions always say to hand tighten but I've always had to give it that extra hit with the Channelocks to stop any leaking.

Comment: Thought it was common for most hand tight joints to add the extra quarter turn.  Think most instructions even recommend the extra quarter turn, and only a few are hand tight only.  Guess it also depends if you are Mr T or the 98 pound weakling on the beach(I did read the ads in the back of comics).

Comment: @crip659  You mean the kid that gets sand kicked in his face and loses his girl???

Answer (score 1):

As Huesmann stated in comments, the weight of the water pushed the pieces apart.

Often what happens over time is the pipes get a little slimy and the plastic compression washer under the big nut gets slippery and... viola  the parts slip apart.

Got to a hardware or big box store and buy a rubber compression washers
like [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-Rubber-Washer-SJ-1-1-2/1002893088?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_208_Plumbing-Repair-_-1002893088-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=Cj0KCQjwt_qgBhDFARIsABcDjOcjuhKJRp7mVfaQ9MhdwvQ660Y-XLL8b1Slfju0T0IqHtr6LDzL2OYaAuF6EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) .   Replace the plastic washer with the rubber. ( The flat wider part goes up, the taper goes down.)  Tighten the nut hand tight and only tighten it more if there is any leak.

You should be good to go.

Comment: A rubber compression washer seems like a good idea, but TBH I have never used one, and never had a slip joint spontaneously slip apart.   I suspect it wasn't tightened enough because it's so short and hard to grapple.   Or the washer is missing.

Comment: Second the recommendation for tapered rubber (or even silicone) slip-joint washers. They are infinitely superior to the crappy hard plastic ones that come standard with cheap Big Box drain fittings. Like these: https://www.truevalue.com/solution-silicone-slip-joint-washers-1-5-in-od-2-pk

Answer (score 0):

You've got the wrong trap fitting for the tail-pipe on the waste.

The waste looks designed for a push-fit
<sup>wrong pipe, but just so you can see the push-fit end</sup>

[image]

…or it should be a threaded waste to fit your screw-fit u-bend

[image]

Comment: OP's basket looks threaded to me.   It has some teflon tape on the tailpiece threads but otherwise like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Kitchen-Assembly-Strainer-Stainless-Rustproof/dp/B006HXZQDA/ref=sr_1_3_sspa).

Comment: Looks like standard slip-joint tubular drain stuff. We don't even have "push-fit" drain stuff in my part of the US.